# .NET MAUI FlyoutItem Multiple With TabBar

Tags: c#, maui

I have:

```
 <FlyoutItem
        FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems"
   </FlyoutItem>
```

I would like to have a TabBar in one of the contentPages but I can't get it.

Comment: Can you explain your scenario more thoroughly? Maybe show a picture of what you're trying to achieve. The way I understand your question is that you want a Flyout Menu for the entire app, made using Shell, and you want to have a bottom TabBar just on one of the pages. You cannot achieve that with Shell alone, AFAIK and you also cannot mix Shell and TabbedPage either. So, you may need to use a third party component, like Sharpnado.Tabs.

Comment: That's it, you got it right, I'll have to use Sharpnado.Tabs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below.

```
<Shell FlyoutBehavior="Flyout">

    <FlyoutItem Title="Home">
        <Tab Title="Tab1">
           <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:Tab1}"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Tab2">
           <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:Tab2}"/>
        </Tab>
   </FlyoutItem>
</Shell>
```

Comment: but I can't put it inside my existing FyloutItem, what you put me will be separated by a gray line and below my menu and it will do a strange effect replacing all the content. I do not know if I explained well.

Answer (score 1):

> but I can't put it inside my existing FyloutItem, what you put me will
> be separated by a gray line and below my menu and it will do a strange
> effect replacing all the content.

I did a test, and there is no gray line.

Please refer to the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiApp1205.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp1205"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout">

    <FlyoutItem Route="animals"
                FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <Tab Title="Domestic"
             Route="domestic"
             >
            <ShellContent Route="cats"
                          Title="Cats"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:CatsPage}" />
            <ShellContent Route="dogs"
                          Title="Dogs"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:DogsPage}" />
        </Tab>

    </FlyoutItem>

    <ShellContent
        Title="Test"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />

</Shell>
```

Comment: umm, what you put me is not for the top tabs?

Comment: It is the top tabs.

Comment: in my question title I put TabBar, what I need is a FlyoutItem menu and TabBar (bottom tabs)